# Passing callback function in NodeJS turns into Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, callback, alexa-skills-kit

I am making an Alexa skill with AWS Lambda functions in NodeJS.

The app is throwing error when I call an Intent:

`"errorMessage": "Exception: TypeError: object is not a function"`

First, my app gets an event. If it's an Intent, it calls:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    try {
           ...
           else if (event.request.type === "IntentRequest") {

             onIntent(
                event.request,
                event.session,
                function intent_callback(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
                    context.succeed(buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                }
             );
```

You can see the above passes a callback to `onIntent()`. It checks which Intent it is. Console.logging here shows the passed through callback as a `function`:

```
function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {

    if ("ItemIntent" === intentName) {
        console.log(callback); // This is a function

        getOrderResponse(intent, session, callback);
```

Yet, the type of the `callback` in `getOrderResponse()` somehow turns into an object? This would be why I'm getting that error, but I don't see how it's not a `function` type here. Why is it an object?

```
function getOrderResponse(callback) {

    console.log('getOrderResponse', callback); // type = Object:  { name: 'ItemIntent', slots: { Item: { name: 'Item' } } }

    var card_title = config.data().CARD_TITLE;

    var sessionAttributes = {},
        speechOutput = 'So you want quick order',
        shouldEndSession = false,
        repromptText = 'Hello';

    sessionAttributes = {
        'speechOutput': repromptText,
        'repromptText': repromptText,
        'questions': 'some questions'
    };

    callback(sessionAttributes, buildSpeechletResponse(card_title, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
}
```

Comment: You're passing `intent` as the first argument to `getOrderResponse`. You should be passing `callback` as the first argument or `getOrderResponse` needs to accept 3 parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The callback will have to be the third parameter.

`getOrderResponse(intent, session, callback);` The first parameter you are sending is the the `intent` object.

`function getOrderResponse(callback) {`

should be

`function getOrderResponse(intent, session, callback) {`